# How to overwrite same text file in c++

Tags: c++

I have a data text file called Flights.txt and below is the data.

VA301

2020.02.23 18.30

COLOMBO

SINGAPORE

10 E AB

15 B CDE

22 E ADF

I have a main menu which goes like this:
Welcome. Please input choice:
1. Disply availble flight
2. Seat availability
3. seat booking
4. Exit

When someone can book the seat like '22' row 'E' class 'A' seat like wise.Then i need to modify my Text file Flight.txt without that seat.It should be '22 E DF' like wise.

This is my flight class

```
class Flight{

    public:
        bool eclass[61][7];
        bool bclass[61][7];
        string flight_name;
        string flight_time;
        string flight_date;
        string depart_city;
        string arriv_city;
        };
```

This is my booking function:

```
cout<<"Enter Flight Number :";
                cin>>flight_name;
                temp = false;
                for(int i=0; i< flightCount; i++){
                    if(flight_name == A[i].flight_name){
                        temp = true;
                        v=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!temp){
                    cout<<"Sorry Invalid Flight Number"<<endl<<endl;
                    break;
                }else{
                    cout<<"Enter your class :";
                    cin>>flight_class;
                    if(flight_class != 'E' && flight_class != 'B'){
                        cout<< "Invalid class"<<endl;
                        break;
                    }else{  
                        cout<<"Enter Row number :";
                        cin>>seat_row;
                        if(seat_row >= 61 || seat_row <= 0){
                            cout<<"Sorry Invalid row number!"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }else{
                            cout<<"Enter column Alphabet :";
                            cin>> seat_col;
                            if(seat_col !='A' && seat_col !='B' && seat_col !='C' && seat_col !='D' && seat_col !='E' && seat_col !='F'){
                                cout<<"Sorry Invalid column Number"<<endl;
                                break;
                            }
                            if(seat_col == 'A'){colm = (int)'A' -64 ;}
                            if(seat_col == 'B'){colm = (int)'B' -64 ;}
                            if(seat_col == 'C'){colm = (int)'C' -64 ;}
                            if(seat_col == 'D'){colm = (int)'D' -64 ;}
                            if(seat_col == 'E'){colm = (int)'E' -64 ;}
                            if(seat_col == 'F'){colm = (int)'F' -64 ;}

                            if(flight_class == 'E'){
                                if(A[v].eclass[seat_row][colm]){
                                    cout<<"Seat is Allocated!!"<<endl;
                                    A[v].eclass[seat_row][colm] = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    cout<<"Sorry Seat is not available!! Try another one"<<endl;
                                }   
                            }
                            if(flight_class == 'B'){
                                if(A[v].bclass[seat_row][colm]){
                                    cout<<"Seat is Allocated!!"<<endl;
                                    A[v].bclass[seat_row][colm] = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    cout<<"Sorry Seat is not available!! Try another one"<<endl;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
```

So please tell me how to modify my text file?

here is my temp file write function. A is "Flight A[5]" object of array.

```
    for(int k=1; k<61; k++){
                    temp = false;
                    for(int j=1; j<7; j++){
                        if(A[i].bclass[k][j]){
                            temp = true ;
                            if( j == 1 ){ fileo<<"A"; }
                            if( j == 2 ){ fileo<<"B"; }
                            if( j == 3 ){ fileo<<"C"; }
                            if( j == 4 ){ fileo<<"D"; }
                            if( j == 5 ){ fileo<<"E"; }
                            if( j == 6 ){ fileo<<"F"; }
                            }
                        }
                        if(temp){
                            fileo<<k<<" "<<"B"<<" "<<endl; 
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Buffer the whole text of the file in a string, modify the buffer and write the buffer all again into the file

Comment: in a sense, your title already has the answer: You overwrite the file.

Comment: why down voted? @RoQuOTriX  Thank you sir and do you recommend Any tutorial for this?

Comment: @Ranindu not really, but I think you could easily find something with "reading whole file into buffer" and then you need "write modified buffer to file"

Comment: did you open the file in append mode?

Answer (score 3):

The problems with texts and text files is that the texts are often of differing length, which means you can't really just overwrite a single string in the file.

First of all it's going to be hard to find the position where the string starts. Then if the new string is shorter you won't overwrite the full old string, or if the new string is longer then you will overwrite other data.

One common way is to read the data, record by record, and rewrite into a new temporary file. When you find the data you need to modify you write the modified data to the new temporary file. Continue until you have read and rewritten all the data from the old original file. Then you rename the new temporary file as the old original file.

Other possibilities include reading all of the file (still record by record) into memory, do the modification on the record(s) that should be modified, and then reopen the file as a brand new (and empty) file and write out the records from the in-memory storage.